# Suppress warnings from Cython

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings, cython, suppress-warnings

I cythonize `*.pyx` files manually using

```
cython -3 -Wextra mymodule.pyx
```

I use the `-Wextra` option to generate additional warnings, useful for cleaning up redundant code pieces. However, many warnings of the form

```
warning: mymodule.pyx:123:45: local variable 'x' might be referenced before assignment
```

are printed, which I do not care for. I understand why it is not obvious from the perspective of the compiler, but under no circumstance is it ever possible for `x` to not be assigned before referencing, in my particular situation.

I would therefore like to keep using `-Wextra` but filter out this type of warning, similar to the `-Wno` option of gcc. I have however not been able to track down such a feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warnings in cython are controlled via compiler directives; they only seem to be partially [documented](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives) currently, but you can see the full list in the Cython [source](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/a4398a4eed261240be894f5263628648e28cae21/Cython/Compiler/Options.py#L188).

In this case you want `warn.maybe_uninitialized`, passed to the `--directive` option.

```
$ cython test.pyx -Wextra
warning: test.pyx:7:12: local variable 'x' might be referenced before assignment

$ cython test.pyx -Wextra --directive warn.maybe_uninitialized=False
# no warning
```